# Issues with Nested ifelse to determine color of AwesomeMarkers

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, colors, leaflet

I am trying to color awesomemarkers for leaflet in R by group according to `unique(df$type)`, although the current code is not grouping the way I envisioned. For example in dfnight, I would like all the "Tacos" markers to be green, "Hamburger" to be orange, and "Elote" to be darkblue no matter which options are selected from the picker. Right now, the colors change depending on what is selected. Any guidance or alternative way to achieve the same goal would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(shinythemes)
#Data Sample

longN <- c(-96.72363, -96.72880, -96.72700, -96.7259757, -96.7261564, -96.7260505)
latN <- c(17.06167, 17.06200, 17.06170, 17.0553262, 17.0543072,17.0548387 )
nameN <- c("jim", "grant", "pablo", "sue", "bob", "frank")
typeN <- c("Tacos", "Hamburger", "Elotes", "Tacos", "Hamburger", "Elotes")

dfnight <- data.frame(long=longN, lat=latN, name = nameN, type=typeN)


longM <- c(-96.72363, -96.72880, -96.72700, -96.7259757, -96.7261564, -96.7260505)
latM <- c(17.06167, 17.06200, 17.06170, 17.0553262, 17.0543072,17.0548387 )
nameM <- c("jim", "grant", "pablo", "sue", "bob", "frank")
typeM <- c("Memelas","Tortas", "Tacos", "Memelas", "Tortas","Tacos")


# #icons

dfmorn <- data.frame(long=longM, lat=latM, name = nameM, type=typeM)

getColorM<-function(dfmorn){
  lapply(dfmorn$type, function(type) {
    ifelse(type == 'Tacos','green', 
           ifelse(type == 'Memelas', 'orange',
           ifelse(type == 'Chips', 'red',
           ifelse(type == 'Snacks', 'blue',
           ifelse (type == 'Sandwhiches', 'purple', 'black'
                            )))))
    
    
  })
}

getColorN <- function(dfnight){
  lapply(dfnight$type, function(type) {
    ifelse(type == 'Tacos', 'green',
                  ifelse(type == 'Hamburguesa','orange',
                  ifelse (type == 'Elotes','darkblue',
                  ifelse (type == 'Plantanos','beige',
                  ifelse (type == 'Tamales','darkgreen',
                  ifelse (type == 'Tlayudas','cadetblue',
                  ifelse (type == 'Tortas','purple', 'black'
                                   )))))))
  })
}

iconsM <- awesomeIcons(
  icon = 'ios-close',
  iconColor = 'black',
  library = 'ion',
  markerColor = getColorM(dfmorn))

iconsN <- awesomeIcons(
  icon = 'ios-close',
  iconColor = 'black',
  library = 'ion',
  markerColor = getColorN(dfnight))


#ui 
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
  titlePanel(title = "Street Food in Historic Center of Oaxaca, Mexico"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "time",
        label = "Select Time",
        choices = c("Day", "Night"),
        selected = "Day"
      ),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "food",
        label = "Type of Food",
        choices = unique(dfmorn$type),
        selected = dfmorn$food[1:5],
        multiple = TRUE)),
    mainPanel(h3("Map"), leafletOutput("map", width = "800", height = "600")))
)

#server
server <- function(input, output, session){ 
  
  observeEvent(input$time, {
    
    if(input$time == "Day") choices <- unique(dfmorn$type)
    else choices <- unique(dfnight$type)
    
    updateSelectInput(
      inputId = "food",
      label = "Type of Food",
      choices = choices,
      select=choices[1:3]
    )
  })
  
  dfmrn <- eventReactive(input$food, {
    if(input$time == "Day") df <- dfmorn
    else df <- dfnight
    df %>% dplyr::filter(type %in% input$food)
  })
  
  observe({print(dfmrn())})
  
  output$map = renderLeaflet({
    req(dfmrn())
    leaflet(data = dfmrn()) %>%
      setView(lng = -96.725, lat = 17.0618, zoom =14)%>%
      addTiles() 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$food, {
    if(input$time == "Day") icons <- iconsM
    else icons <- iconsN
    leafletProxy("map", session) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      addAwesomeMarkers( 
        data = dfmrn(),
        lng = ~long,
        lat = ~lat,
        icon = icons,
        label = ~as.character(type)
      )
  })
  
}

#Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

Updated code using list()

```
getColorM<- list("Tacos"= "green", "Memelas" = "orange", "Tortas" = "purple")
                 #"Chips" = "red", "Snacks"= "blue", )

getcolorN <-list("Tacos"= "green", "Hamburger" = "orange", "Elotes" = "darkblue")
                 #"Papas" = "red", "Antojitos"= "blue", "Tortas" = "purple",
                 #"Marquesitas"= "pink", "Platanos" = "biege", "Antojitos"= "blue", "Tamales" = "darkgreen", "Tlayudas" = "cadetblue")

iconsM <- awesomeIcons(
  icon = 'ios-close',
  iconColor = 'black',
  library = 'ion',
  markerColor <- getColorM[dfmorn$type] )

iconsN <- awesomeIcons(
  icon = 'ios-close',
  iconColor = 'black',
  library = 'ion',
  markerColor <-getcolorN[dfnight$type])
```

[image: Red Color Markers]

Comment: Why not use a list? `foodColors <- list("Tacos" = "green", "Memelas" = "orange", ...etc...)` and then `markerColor <- foodColors[dfnight$type]`.

Comment: Thanks @dash2 I tried with a list as you mentioned although now all the markers show up as red. Any ideas about this? I will put new code in post.

Comment: You seem to be using `markerColor <-` inside your list instead of `markerColor = `. My suggestion would be, work on your R basics to understand the difference between assignment and argument passing. It'll be worth it in the long run for this very steep-learning-curve language.

Comment: @dash2 I tried both `markerColor <-` and also `markerColor =` and both produce the result above with red markers. Any other suggestions? Thanks for your help

Comment: if you do `getcolorN[dfnight$type]` at the command line, what do you see?

Comment: @dash2 ```getcolorN[dfnight$type]
$Tacos
[1] "green"

$Hamburger
[1] "orange"

$Elotes
[1] "darkblue"

$Tacos
[1] "green"

$Hamburger
[1] "orange"

$Elotes
[1] "darkblue"

> ```

Comment: That looks right to me, so you need to figure out why those colours aren't getting to your call to `awesomeIcons()`. Time to break out the debugger :-)